# Can we think of Overnight Index Swaps as short-term IRS?

Tags: finance, interest-rate-swap, economics

OIS are a series of fixed-rate cashflows discounted at the overnight rate, swapped for overnight (floating) rate.

IRS are similarly discounted fixed-rate cashflows, swapped on an IBOR-floating rate.

Since both of them are used to swap between fixed rate payment and float rate payment, can we think of OIS as short-term IRS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept is similar, but the mechanics are slightly different. Making a quarterly payment based on 3-month Libor is fine, but making daily payments of the overnight rate is inconvenient (too much work in the back-office making and checking the payments), so a single payment is made at maturity (or on the annual anniversary of the swap's inception), based on a mathematical geometric averaging formula applied to all the overnight rates.

Answer (score 6):

An Interest Rate Swap (IRS) normally refers a swap between a fixed rate and a floating rate. Floating rate being a single fixing for each accrual period and payment.

An overnight indexed interest-rate swap will have the daily overnight index compounded throughout the accrual period.  A vanilla IRS will not compound during the accrual, being a term rate.